# Please explain the algebraic manipulations between these two formulas for Stirling numbers of the second kind

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, stirling-numbers

$$\begin{align}\\
S(n,r) &= \frac1{r!}\sum_{i = 0}^r (-1)^i\binom r i(r-i)^n\\
&= \frac1{r!}\sum_{i = 0}^r (-1)^{r-i}\binom r i i^n\\
\end{align}$$

I know how to derive the formula in the first line using inclusion-exclusion, but:

How did we go from the first line to the second?

Comment: Let $i=r-k$, since $i$ and $k$ are dummy variables, also $C_k^r=C_{r-k}^r$ , it can be written in the expression in the second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$S(n,r)=\frac1{r!}\sum_{i = 0}^r (-1)^i\binom{r}{i}(r-i)^n$$

Note that $i$ runs from $0$ to $r$, but we can also run from $r$ to $0$, which is equivalent with replacing all $i$'s with $r-i$. We get

$$S(n,r)=\frac1{r!}\sum_{i = 0}^r (-1)^{r-i}\binom{r}{r-i}(r-(r-i))^n$$

Note that $\binom{r}{r-i}=\binom{r}{i}$ so that this reduces to

$$S(n,r)=\frac1{r!}\sum_{i = 0}^r (-1)^{r-i}\binom{r}{i}i^n$$

en that's the last line.

Comment: What do you mean we can run from $r$ to $0$. Why is that true? Do you mean, just reversing the order in which sums will appear? For instance $\sum_{i=r}^0$?

Comment: @AlJebr, yes, that's what I mean. However, it's quite uncommon to write $\sum_{i=r}^0$, since the lower bound is then higher then the upper bound (which would then be the [Empty Sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_sum), since then you're summing no terms). I'm sorry for the confusion. Tell me if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Why does having the sum run from $r$ to $0$ change the $i$'s with $r-i$?

Comment: Because, if we let $i$ run from $0$ to $r$, then $r-i$ runs from $r$ to $0$